# Raphael - rotate whole set not each object

Tags: svg, rotation, raphael

Hi guys i'm trying to rotate few objects at once with Set using Element.animate() but it rotates each element not the whole set and i need whole set

Help me please i'm very new to raphael just about few hours of reading docs and trying functions

```
            var archtype = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600);

            archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
                var alpha = 360 / total * value,
                a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
                x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
                y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
                path;
                if (total == value) {
                    path = [["M", xloc, yloc - R],["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]];
                } else {
                    path = [["M", xloc, yloc - R],["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
                }
                return {
                    path: path
                };
            };

            var circleSet=archtype.set();

            var arc_red0 = archtype.path().attr({
               "stroke": "#f00",
               "stroke-width": 30,
               arc: [300, 300, 30, 360, 250]
            });
            circleSet.push(arc_red0);

            var arc_red1 = archtype.path().attr({
               "stroke": "#f00",
               "stroke-width": 30,
               arc: [300, 300, 20, 360, 250],
               "transform": "r50,300,300"
            });
            circleSet.push(arc_red1);

            var arc_red2 = archtype.path().attr({
               "stroke": "#f00",
               "stroke-width": 30,
               arc: [300, 300, 80, 360, 250],
               "transform": "r90,300,300"
            });
            circleSet.push(arc_red2);

            var arc_red3 = archtype.path().attr({
               "stroke": "#f00",
               "stroke-width": 30,
               arc: [300, 300, 60, 360, 250],
               "transform": "r190,300,300"
            });
            circleSet.push(arc_red3);

            var arc_red4 = archtype.path().attr({
               "stroke": "#f00",
               "stroke-width": 30,
               arc: [300, 300, 70, 360, 250],
               "transform": "r270,300,300"
            });
            circleSet.push(arc_red4);

            var $angle=0;

            (function (){
                circleSet.animate({transform:"r"+$angle+",300,300"},200);
                $angle++;

                init = false;
                setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60);
            })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use Raphael's `sets` feature -- Add all the elements to a set, and then tell Raphael to rotate the set. See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set for more info.

This won't actually rotate the whole Raphael element, but if all elements of the image are part of the set, it will look like it is doing so.

Option 2: Use standard CSS to rotate the element or it's HTML container. This might actually be the simplest option, but has the down-side that it won't work in older browsers (particularly old versions of IE). There are work-arounds for this (eg [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896)), but if you're already using Raphael to aid IE compatibility you may not want to have to use another script as well.